# Is it possible to look for an instance of a particular value in a Azure Data Factory expression?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I return a JSON array from a TSQL procedure to Azure Data Factory. I want to know if at least 1 value in the array is equal to true. The JSON array has multiple fields included and multiple rows.

**Setup overview**:

1. Data Factory lookup activity.
2. TSQL procedure that returns 2 or more
   rows.
3. Data Factory IF activity with conditional that checks JSON
   returned for at least 1 instance of x.

**Dummy procedure**:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_dummyProc
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 1, 'a', 1
    UNION
    SELECT 2, 'b', 0
    ;
```

**Data Factory pipe**:

[image]

**I tried**:

```
@contains(activity('ActivityName').output.value.SqlFieldName, true)
```

**Which, unsurprisingly led to**:

> The expression
> 'contains(activity('ActivityName').output.value.SqlFieldName, true)'
> cannot be evaluated because property 'SqlFieldName' cannot be
> selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index.

I cannot see an expression component that can iterate over the list returned to check for a value. I could write another procedure to deal with this, but ideally, I would prefer not to need to do so every time I want to solve this problem. [This is where I looked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#contains).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast your the result of activity('ActivityName').output.value to String, then use `contains()` to check whether it contains '"SqlFieldName":true'. Something like the following expression: `@contains(join(activity('ActivityName').output.value,','),'"SqlFieldName":true')`